# What's the difference between A<:B and +B in Scala?

Tags: scala, variance

What's the difference between

```
[A <: B]
```

and

```
[+B]
```

in Scala?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

`Q[A <: B]` means that class `Q` can take any class `A` that is a subclass of `B`.

`Q[+B]` means that `Q` can take *any* class, but if `A` is a subclass of `B`, then `Q[A]` is considered to be a subclass of `Q[B]`.

`Q[+A <: B]` means that class `Q` can only take subclasses of `B` as well as propagating the subclass relationship.

The first is useful when you want to do something generic, but you need to rely upon a certain set of methods in `B`.  For example, if you have an `Output` class with a `toFile` method, you could use that method in any class that could be passed into `Q`.

The second is useful when you want to make collections that behave the same way as the original classes.  If you take `B` and you make a subclass `A`, then you can pass `A` in anywhere where `B` is expected.  But if you take a *collection* of `B`, `Q[B]`, is it true that you can always pass in `Q[A]` instead?  In general, no; there are cases when this would be the wrong thing to do.  But you can say that this is the right thing to do by using `+B` (covariance; `Q` covaries--follows along with--`B`'s subclasses' inheritance relationship).

Comment: Can you give an example and explanation for the use of contravariant?
What Q[-A] means ?

Answer (score 46):

I would like to extend [Rex Kerr's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531696/3041008) with some more examples:
Let's say we have four classes:

```
 class Animal {}
 class Dog extends Animal {}

 class Car {}
 class SportsCar extends Car {}
```

### Let's start with variance:

```
 case class List[+B](elements: B*) {} // simplification; covariance like in original List

 val animals: List[Animal] = List( new Dog(), new Animal() )
 val cars: List[Car] = List ( new Car(), new SportsCar() )
```

As you can see **List does not care whether it contains Animals or Cars**. The developers of List did not enforce that e.g. only Cars can go inside Lists.

Additionally:

```
case class Shelter(animals: List[Animal]) {}

val animalShelter: Shelter = Shelter( List(new Animal()): List[Animal] )
val dogShelter: Shelter = Shelter( List(new Dog()): List[Dog] )
```

If a function expects a `List[Animal]` parameter you can also pass a `List[Dog]` as an argument to the function instead. `List[Dog]` **is considered a subclass of** `List[Animal]` due to the covariance of List. It would not work if List was invariant.

### Now onto type bounds:

```
case class Barn[A <: Animal](animals: A*) {}

val animalBarn: Barn[Animal] = Barn( new Dog(), new Animal() )
val carBarn = Barn( new SportsCar() )
/* 
error: inferred type arguments [SportsCar] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [A <: Animal]
    val carBarn = Barn(new SportsCar())
                 ^
*/
```

As you can see **Barn is a collection only intended for Animals**. No cars allowed in here.

Comment: `Animal`-`Dog` / `Car`-`SportsCar` classes are always best examples. It's pretty hard to follow all those `Q`, `A`, `B`s.

Comment: In `List[Car]` we can of course add `SportsCar`, even if it was declared as  `List[B]`. If we had function like `def smth(x:MyList[Car]):Unit = {}`, passing `List[SportsCar]` would fail for `List[B]`, but not for `List[+B]`, because now `List[SportsCar]` is subclass of `List[Car]`, and we can pass sub classes in place of original class.

Answer (score 4):

I found this blog post while researching this question.  Gives an even deeper explanation of Scala variance including its theoretical basis in  Category Theory

http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/01/covariance-and-contravariance-in-scala/

Answer (score 2):

for my Understanding:

---

The first is a parameter type bound, there a upper and lower typebounds in our case its a "type parameter A that is a subtype of B (or B itself).

---

The second is a Variance Annotation for a class defintion, in our case a covariance subclassing of B

---

Scala: +  Java: ? extends T    Covariant subclassing

Scala: -  Java: ? super T      Contravariant subclassing