# Understanding Type Parameters

Tags: scala

Looking at part of the `IO Monad`'s signatures from [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/):

```
trait IO[+A] { self =>
  def run: A
  def map[B](f: A => B): IO[B] =
    new IO[B] { def run = f(self.run) }
```

As I understand, `IO[+A]` means that the `IO` type takes a type parameter of "A or its subclasses."

Looking at `def map[B]...`, `B` is a type involved in this function. It's useful to use `map[B](f: A => B): IO[B]` since, as I understand, you can list `B` as a return type of `f`, as well as the returned type parameter of `IO`?

So, the following implementation would cause a compile-time problem:

`map(f: Int => String): IO[Int]`

Comment: Sorry, what's the question? ;)

Comment: basically I'm looking for confirmation/more details in my above  example, please :)

Comment: I hope I answered your question. I think it's a good question but it's not easily worded.

Comment: @KevinMeredith You're curious about variance in Scala types? Check out this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663254/scala-covariance-contravariance-question

Comment: Thanks @wheaties. I've read that post and this solid ones from Rex Kerr (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4531455/whats-the-difference-between-ab-and-b-in-scala). I'm learning more each time I read it (and review questions like my above one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `+A` means similar thing as `T <: A`. That means "for all subtypes of A including A". This "limitation" is useful here because you are supposed to pass `f` function to the `map` method and you are restricting it to specific type `A` and it's subtypes. Thus when you extend the trait in your class you allow for substitution of `f` while being typesafe.

`B` here is a result of applying `f` to `A`. Since it's a Monad you get back not just `B` but an `IO[B]`. In other words it might fail and you might get `B` wrapped in "success" or some sort of "failure".

Notice that the type of `self` is `+A`, and a newly created `IO[B]` does not actually compute anything, it just wraps around result of a `run` which has to be `B`. Since you expect failures to occur in IO and since it's a Monad you wrap around the result of an application of `f(self.run)` creating a monad `IO[B]` (as promised by `map` method signature).

Finally, as you said `map(f: Int => String): IO[Int]` should not compile since `Int` is not a subtype of `String`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "implementation" in this context: `map(f: Int => String): IO[Int]`. If you mean calling `map` passing a function `Int => String`, then that returns `IO[String]` -- the callee doesn't get a say in what type is returned.

If you mean overriding the implementation of `map` (which you shouldn't do) with `override def map(f: Int => String): IO[String]`, then that *isn't* overriding anything, because you can't remove a type parameter when overriding, and you can't change the type of the parameters it receives either, and you can change the return type to a subtype, but `IO[String]` isn't a subtype of `IO[B]` so that's different as well.